# How can I set the javascript path in my JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, path, resources

I am working on SpringMVC3.2, JSP and Tomcat using Maven build. My web application structure is shown like below.

```
tomcat
  |-- webapps
    |-- MyApp
      |-- css
      |-- js
        |-- jquery.js
      |-- images
      |-- META-INF
      |-- WEB-INF
        |-- classes
        |-- lib
        |-- src
        |-- web.xml
        |-- pages
             |-- index.jsp
```

I set the JavaScript path in the index.jsp like following:

```
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

But it could not load the Javascript file. I changed path and moved the file here and there but everything did not work. What am I missing? Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT
Actually, I found the answer through different community.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@page isELIgnored="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="${contextPath}/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is not a beautiful way but it works fine for me and if you want different solution then see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
tomcat
  |-- webapps
    |-- YourApplicatipName
      |-- css
      |-- js
        |-- jquery.js
      |-- images
      |-- META-INF
      |-- WEB-INF
        |-- classes
        |-- lib
        |-- src
        |-- web.xml
```

th js folder should be in your root folder only

now your given path would work

Comment: Thanks for the quick and kind reply. Do you mean I have to put the js folder just under WebRoot? I will try it again.

Comment: @sunghun : i have made an edit considering you are keeping js folder in the tomcat root , but you should keep it inside your application folder , is it the case ??

Comment: Hussain, I updated the structure. The js file has been already inside of my application.

Answer (score 0):

web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
<page-encoding>UTF-8</page-encoding>
<scripting-invalid>true</scripting-invalid>
<include-prelude>/WEB-INF/common/commonDefinition.jspf</include-prelude>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

commonDefinition.jspf

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %><%@ 
taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %><%@ 
taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %><%@ 
taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %><%@ 
taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
```